# Apache reload skipping vhost on error

Tags: apache, configuration-files, restart, vhosts

I have several vhost configured with there own conf file under conf.d. This works fine, but ever so often i have to make changes to one of the files and the reload apache. Is there a way where apache would skip that file if there is an error so that the other sites still goes up on a reload?

This is a prod site (and yes i should test all first, but that is not always practical).
It would be nice if I could change the file for domain1.conf do a service httpd restart and then if there is an error in the file that today would cause apache not to start at all it would simply skip that conf file and load start with all the others.

Hope this would work

Regards

Tore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick

```
apachectl configtest
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/774719/make-apache-reload-skipping-vhost-on-error